# Há algo de errado com a minha resposta?

Tags: debate, voto-contra

Vi esta pergunta:

> [Verificar se a página html existe HTML/Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231970/3635)

Não achei de todo mal, não negativei e nem positivei, de inicio nem iria responder, mas ao ver as respostas que me senti no dever de explicar de fato o que é um site online/offline e o que são respostas HTTP, claro que não entrei muito em detalhes:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231994/3635

O usuário Godfrey comenteou para o AP:

> Você não especificou se quer verificar uma página do mesmo domínio ou não. Se for de um domínio diferente do da sua aplicação, você não conseguirá fazer essa verificação por conta do CORS.

No entanto para mim não faz sentido verificar se um site esta online se você já esta no site, eu entendo perfeitamente que o AP pediu **sem PHP**, mas se fosse possível sem eu com certeza teria formulado um exemplo **sem**. No entanto **não há solução confiável** sem tecnologias no back-end devido ao CORs como tentei deixar claro na minha resposta.

O outro usuário me criticou falando para tirar a parte dos exemplos PHP, mas elas tem um fundamento, explicar sobre verificar se um site esta online apenas ou até verificar a resposta HTTP pelo status (`fsockopen` vs `curl`), no entanto mesmo assim acabei por receber dois downvotes.

Afinal há algum problema na resposta que não estou enxergando?

Comment: Existe vários problemas na pergunta do AP, mas sua resposta salvou ela. Mesmo assim eu votei para fechar a pergunta como não clara, porque as pessoas vão entender de forma errada e vão achar que estão fazendo o certo, mesmo fazendo o errado. E em relação a sua resposta, ela está ótima e pode ajudar outras pessoas além do AP.

Comment: Nesse momento a resposta mais objetiva que eu consigo te dar é "ao menos dez pessoas acham que sua resposta é boa, e um acha que tem algo errado"... :P

Comment: @Bacco eram 2, alguém removeu o voto hehehe

Answer (score 7):

Tem dois tipos de respostas que eu, **particularmente**, não gosto de ver na comunidade e costumo negativar - junto com uma orientação (se eu julgar válido)¹:

- Respostas que possuem apenas códigos, sem explicação alguma, o que eu julgo de pouca utilidade para a comunidade em geral;
- Respostas que apenas apresentam uma solução que funciona, diferente da proposta na pergunta, sem explicar o problema/particularidades da solução que o autor da pergunta propôs ou das outras respostas;

Li a sua resposta na totalidade e não julguei que se caracteriza em nenhuma nas duas classes acima. Em verdade, ela se caracteriza como o tipo de resposta que eu mais gosto de ver aqui:

- Respostas que explicam o porquê dos conceitos/códigos apresentados na pergunta estarem errado **e** apresentarem alternativas que possam orientar não só o autor da pergunta como outros usuários sobre os conceitos a serem analisados ao tentar solucionar o problema;

Portanto, digo que, na minha opinião, não há nada de ruim em manter a parte do PHP, mesmo sendo explicitado na pergunta que seria apenas *front-end*, pois antes de apresentar esta solução você apresentou motivos de não se fazer a verificação no *front-end*, mas sim no *back-end*.

As duas perguntas que eu me faço ao avaliar uma resposta (inclusive as minhas próprias):

1. De alguma forma esta resposta traz conteúdo saudável que pode ser absorvido pela comunidade?
2. De alguma forma esta resposta pode trazer qualquer tipo de prejuízo à comunidade?

Se as respostas forem Sim e Não, respectivamente, eu considero como uma boa resposta; caso contrário, julgo que a resposta é passível de edição ou exclusão (em casos extremos).

<sub>1 - Alguns usuários já foram inúmeras vezes orientados e não mudaram o comportamento, então nesses casos eu evito o comentário para evitar intrigas. É direito dele continuar postando respostas da forma que acha melhor, assim como é direito meu negativar se eu não concordar.</sub>